# Best Practice Using Django Signal (For user authentication?)

Tags: django

I am new to Django and want to know deeper about the concept of signals.
I know how it works but really don't understand when should one really use it.
From the doc it says **'They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.'**

What are some real applications that use signals for its advantage?

e.x. I'm trying to make a phone verification after user signup. Because it can be integrated inside the single app and the event that interested for the signal is only this 'verify' function, therefore I don't really need signal. I can just pass the information from one view to the other, rather than using pre_save signal from the registration.

I'm sorry if my question is kind of basic. But I really want to know some insight what is the real application, in which many codes interested in one particular event and what are some trade off in my application.
Thanks!!

Comment: Do a google search for Publish/Subscribe pattern, producer/consumer pattern, and observer pattern to get an idea of some examples of "when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events"

Comment: Signals are often an anti-pattern: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ especially since there are a lot of ways to circument these, like updating records in bulk with `.bulk_update` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Often signals is used when you need to do some database-specific low-level stuff. For example, if you use ElasticSearch for better searching documents on your site, you may want to automatically update search indexes, when new document is created or old one was edited.

Also you may have some complex logic of managing database objects. For example, you may need some specific logic of deleting object. For example, when user is deleted, you may want change all the links to his profile by some placeholder, or when new message is created or other action is performed by user, you want to update "last visited" field in user's profile and there's no direct relation between this action and updating the profile.

But when you're just implementing business-logic as in your example with verification, you don't need to use signals, because you don't need any universal logic related to deleting/creating/editing any object: you have a certain object with which you work and can do stuff directly.